# Large files not accepted in AWS Ubuntu instance

Tags: php, flutter, php-ini

I am working on a Flutter app trying to upload images and videos to an AWS Ubuntu instance.

This is the function to upload the file to the server:

```
void _upload(File file) {
    if (file == null) return;
    setState(() {
    

    });
    String base64Image = base64Encode(file.readAsBytesSync());
    String fileName = file.path.split("/").last;

    http.post(phpEndPoint, body: {
      "image": base64Image,
      "name": fileName,
    }).then((res) async {
      print(res.statusCode);
      setState(() {
        print("***********SOURCE subido:"+this.source.toString());
        if(this.source.toString() == "MediaSource.image"){
          Toast.show(
              "Imagen subida", context,
              duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
              gravity: Toast.CENTER,
              backgroundColor: Color(0xff01A0C7),
              textColor: Colors.white);
          incrementNumFotos(context);
        }
        if(this.source.toString() == "MediaSource.video"){
          Toast.show(
              "Video subido", context,
              duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
              gravity: Toast.CENTER,
              backgroundColor: Color(0xff01A0C7),
              textColor: Colors.white);
          incrementNumVideos(context);
        }
      });
    }).catchError((err) {
      print(err);
    });
  }
```

This is the PHP script that receives and stores the sended file:

```
<?php
  $image = $_POST['image'];
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $realImage = base64_decode($image);
  
  file_put_contents($name,$realImage);
  echo "OK";
?>
```

The issue that I am having is that the large files are not stored.

I have updated the file php.ini at the server:

```
upload_max_filesize = 128M
post_max_size =64M
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 300
```

I have tried to upload files with different filesize.

A file with size = 5313566 bytes is uploaded.
A file with size = 8891426 bytes is not uploaded.

Comment: Your ini should have `memory_limit` > `post_max_size` > `upload_max_filesize` see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64455392/2079345 (bottom part of answer)

Comment: @chiliNUT, my php.ini file has memory_limit = 128M, post_max_size = 100M and upload_max_filesize = 100M

Comment: You may need the values well over the size of the file you are uploading. I'd try to make all values at least double the size of the large file

Comment: Additionally if the upload is failing the error log on the php server should provide some insight